# Search Multiple Items in Multiple columns

Tags: php, sql, mysql, search

I have 6 select items in a form. I want to search those 6 in MYSQL DB. I can retrieve results if I use only one, like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wsinmuebles WHERE Property_Type LIKE '%{$_POST['Property_Type']}%'");
```

But when I try more, I get no results!

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wsinmuebles WHERE 
Property_Type LIKE '%{$_POST['Property_Type']}%' AND 
Estado LIKE '%{$_POST['Estado']}%' AND 
Ciudad LIKE '%{$_POST['Ciudad']}%' AND 
Urbanizacion LIKE '%{$_POST['Urbanizacion']}%' AND 
Operacion LIKE '%{$_POST['Operacion']}%' AND 
Precio_bsf LIKE '%{$_POST['Precio_bsf']}%'");
```

This comes from a form by the POST method.

What I need is to look for Property_Type, Estado, Ciudad, Urbanizacion, Operacion and Precio_bsf variables in MYSQL DB, and receive only the results that match all those values.

Comment: If you run the same query from the mysql command-line client, with explicit values instead of variables, do you get any results?  Also, do you really want to match ALL six conditions?

Comment: Yes Jim, i need to match them all. Something like this http://www.entreinmuebles.com.ve/

Answer (score 1):

Dont use And use Or between criteria, and after all you should know that concatenating strings and executing queries is giving possible SQL Injection, that is when instead of your search string I end your query and execute given action, for example "' and 1=1; delete wsinmuebles" if this is my serach query you will lose all your data.

```
  $result = mysql_query("select * from tbl1 where Name='".mysql_escape_string ($_POST["value"]."'" );
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice to avoid SQL Injection. I do not understand really what you mean. Can you give me some code, please.?? Sorry, I am new with this, actually I retrive that code reading a lot over Internet.! Thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

First, escape the post values using mysql_real_escape_string ([Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)) to avoid any SQL injection attacks and also issues with the data having **'** characters.

Second echo the query and run it against the database and check the table data to see if the
query indeed should return some values or may be there are no matches when include the rest   of criteria since you mentioned that you are expecting the results **that match all those values.**

Answer (score 0):

If a field, say Urbanizacion is null, your query will not return it.

```
Urbanizacion LIKE '%%'   =>   FALSE when Urbanizacion is Null
```

You will need to handle Nulls.  I also strongly urge you to protect the code from SQL Injection using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM wsinmuebles WHERE 
    IFNULL(Property_Type,'') LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Property_Type']) ."' AND 
    IFNULL(Estado,'') LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Estado']). "' AND 
    IFNULL(Ciudad,'') LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Ciudad']) ."' AND 
    IFNULL(Urbanizacion,'') LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Urbanizacion']) ."' AND 
    IFNULL(Operacion,'') LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Operacion']) ."' AND 
    IFNULL(Precio_bsf,'') LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Precio_bsf']) ."'");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I will take your advice to avoid injections. But still with the search problem.! :( Thanks.!

Comment: Did you take in the comment about NULLs?

Comment: It does not work.. :( I do not know why but If i use 2 AND, they work great. But If I use more than 2 AND, I get NOT RESULTS FOUND. :S

Comment: Have you added the `mysql_real_escape_string`'s to your query? You could have unescaped characters breaking the query