# Search Multiple tables?

Tags: php, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search Multiple Items in Multiple colums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823068/search-multiple-items-in-multiple-colums)
>   [Search Multiple Tables at in one query (MySQL/PHP#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254165/search-multiple-tables-at-in-one-query-mysql-php)

I've built this simple search script that searches users by name. I want to expand this slightly so that it can search both display name and location? could someone please let me know if this is possible and guide me in the right direction? Thanks.

```
    <form method="get" action="">
<label>Search For: </label><input type="text" name="query" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Search" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset"
</form>

<?php
//PHP CODE STARTS HERE

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

// Change the fields below as per the requirements
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_password="";
$db_name="telecom";
$db_tb_name="ptb_profiles";
$db_tb_atr_name="display_name"; 

//Now we are going to write a script that will do search task
// leave the below fields as it is except while loop, which will display results on screen

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE 

$db_tb_atr_name like '%".$query."%'" );
echo "<h2>Search Results</h2><ol>";
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
{
    echo "<li>";
    echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160);
    echo "</li><hr/>";
}
echo "</ol>";

mysql_close();
}
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254165/search-multiple-tables-at-in-one-query-mysql-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

How about this, you can add `OR` and add another condition. you can add `AND` instead if that's what you want:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$db_tb_name` 
        WHERE display_name like '%".$query."%' 
        OR location LIKE '%".$query."%'"
```